# Why I need to set upstream on a local branch when I have added git remote add already?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a question about git... supposed I cloned my project with this code

```
git clone ssh://git@<my-project.git>
```

and then executed a line like this to add remote upstream link

```
git remote add upstream ssh://git@<my-project.git>
```

When I try to run this line, I have verified that my upstream was set

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@<my-project.git> (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@<my-project.git> (push)
upstream        ssh://git@<my-project.git> (fetch)
upstream        ssh://git@<my-project.git> (push)
```

So I created a new branch taken from the master

```
git checkout -b sample-branch master
Switched to a new branch 'sample-branch'
```

But when I am trying to push my local branch, I am getting below error.

```
git push

fatal: The current branch sample-branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin sample-branch
```

Maybe I am thinking that since I have add an upstream already that my local branch does not need to
set my upstream or I maybe thinking wrong?  I have to execute the line above first before I can execute

```
git push
```

on succeeding commands.

Answer (score 2):

For the TL;DR version, see [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60033618/1256452).

`git remote add` adds a *remote*.  Remotes can have any name you like, though by convention, `origin` is the first one, and `upstream` is often the second.  But normally if you added a second remote it would have a *different* URL, not the same URL.  You only need more than one remote if you talk to multiple different Git repositories, each at different URLs.

Confusingly, the remote named `upstream` (assuming you have one) is not an upstream, it's just a remote.

The term *upstream*, when applied to a branch name, refers to what is internally a two-part setting (as [VonC said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60033618/1256452)).  Every branch name, such as `master` or `feature`, can have one upstream, or no upstream.  Typically the upstream of `master` would be `origin/master` and the upstream of `feature` would be `origin/feature`.  If you did have multiple remotes, and called the second one `upstream`, you could set the upstream of `branchX` to `upstream/branchX`.

So: the *upstream* of a branch is some other name, typically one starting with the name of a *remote*.  Git uses this setting to remember "that's where I fetch/pull from" and "that's where I push to".  This name *must actually exist*, though, and that's where things really get confusing.

> So I created a new branch taken from the master
>
> ```
> git checkout -b sample-branch master
> Switched to a new branch 'sample-branch'
> ```

Technically, this creates a new branch name in your own Git repository, named `sample-branch`.  The commit hash ID selected *by* this new branch name is the same as the commit hash ID selected by the existing name `master` (also a branch name).

When you use this kind of `git checkout` command, your Git will set the upstream of the new branch to the *name* of the other branch *if* it is, say, `origin/sample-branch`.  But you probably don't *have* an `origin/sample-branch`.  This name would only exist if the Git over at `origin`—at the URL stored in the *remote* named `origin`, that is—has a branch named `sample-branch`, and your Git had seen this and copied it over.  Since you didn't use `origin/sample-branch` here—and if you did, it would just fail anyway—your Git *didn't* set an upstream for the new branch.

You need to do something eventually about this.  There's no need to do this right away!  You can do it whenever you like.  But eventually, you do need to do it.  There are two steps involved:

1. You must get the other Git, the one over on `origin`, to create a branch named `sample-branch`.  When you get that Git to create *its* `sample-branch`, *your* Git can now copy that to your `origin/sample-branch`, so that your `origin/sample-branch` exists.
2. Once your `origin/sample-branch` exists, you need to get *your* Git to set `origin/sample-branch` as the upstream for `sample-branch`.

You *can* do this two step process with two separate Git commands, and in the ancient past, you *had* to do it that way.  With modern Git versions, though, one command suffices.  That one command is `git push -u origin sample-branch`.

What this does is:

1. Have your Git call up their Git (the Git at `origin`) using the URL stored in the name `origin`.

   Your Git offers their Git any new commits and other objects required to complete the overall task.  Your Git will then send commits and their contained files if needed.  Once they have everything required, your Git then sends them a polite request: *Please, if it's OK, create or update your name `sample-branch` so that it identifies a particular commit.*   The particular commit your Git recommends here is the same commit that *your* name `sample-branch` identifies.

   If they accept this request, that creates their `sample-branch`.  Since your Git now sees that their Git has `sample-branch`, your Git creates your `origin/sample-branch` to remember this.
2. Now that your Git has `origin/sample-branch`, your `git push -u` automatically invokes `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/sample-branch sample-branch`.

If you wish, for some reason, to do this the old two-step way, run:

```
git push origin sample-branch:sample-branch
```

(the two names here separated by the colon tell your Git what to tell their Git).  Then, when that has succeeded, run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/sample-branch sample-branch
```

Obviously the single `git push -u` command is shorter and easier.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an upstream remote differs from setting an upstream branch (which is a remote+a remote branch name): your second remote should not be needed at all.
See "[Upstream (as related to) Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)".

Try first:

```
 git push -u origin sample-branch
```

Then `git branch -avv`: you will see your branch associated to a remote one.

A `git push` will then work for the next commits publication.

Comment: (I think you mean `git push -u origin sample-branch`, in this case.)

Comment: @torek Right, thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The two existing answers to into a lot of theory as to why, *by default*, you need to do this other thing, because your question implied a lack of understanding regarding the difference between the upstream remote, and the upstream tracking branch for your local branch.

In my opinion the shorter/better answer to your question, however, is that **you shouldn't need to**.

If you're running git 2.37+ and you run the following commands, git will behave the way you, and most people in my experience, would expect it to:

```
git config --global branch.autoSetupMerge simple
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
```

When you branch locally with the same name as a remote branch, the existing remote upstream will be set as the tracking branch, and `git pull` and `git push` will work as you expect (as they do now).

When you branch locally with a *different* name, no tracking branch will initially be set - `git pull` will not work yet. When you first `git push`, the new remote branch you are pushing will be set up as your new remote tracking branch, and `git pull` and `git push` will work as you expect - pushing and pulling to/from the remote branch you created in your first "push".

I don't know whether these configuration options will ever become the defaults, but in my opinion they would avoid a substantial amount of consternation from a large proportion of git users, especially as they start to use it.