# Why line with "fetch" in git config effects how `git branch --set-upstream-to` work?

Tags: git

I took me a while to understand root cause of "strange" results I noted recently with my repo. Below is simple reperformance, works as I understand with any repo with remote origin and main branch:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
```

Now edit `.git/config`

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = /tmp/test/p0-bkup
was:
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
replace with:
    fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
```

Result is now different:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
Branch 'main' set up to track remote ref 'refs/remotes/origin/main'.
```

And in `config` now:

```
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/remotes/origin/main
```

not `merge = refs/heads/main`

For those curious why I think it is important, `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*` is written in config e.g. after `git clone --mirror`

Why line for `fetch` affects `git branch --set-upstream-to`? I thought that line is what `fetch` should do. TIA. Bonus questions: how fetch line was processed and was used to produce each of the results? Any use case for mirrored repo for way it works?

Added:

Below is the code I use now to test `git` by creating simple repos in `/tmp`, for my question it has output at the end:

```
#!/bin/bash

test_dir=/tmp/test
if [ -d $test_dir ] ; then rm --recursive --dir --force $test_dir/* ; else mkdir $test_dir; fi
file_name=text.txt
cd $test_dir

edit_file_and_commit(){
    echo "$1" | tee --append $file_name
    git add $file_name
    git commit -m "$1"
}

print_and_run(){
    echo next line: "$1"
    $1 # echo "$($1)"
}

print_and_run_2() {
    printf "next line:"
    printf " '%s'" "$@"
    printf "\n"
    echo "$("$@")"
}

pause(){ echo; echo pause, type exit to end the pause; bash; }

echo;echo now in p0
mkdir p0 && cd $_
git init
touch $file_name
edit_file_and_commit "commit main-1 in p0"
git branch --move main # rename in case default is master
git checkout -b devel
edit_file_and_commit "commit devel-1 in p0"
git checkout main
edit_file_and_commit "commit main-2 in p0"

touch text2
git add text2
git commit -m "text2"
git checkout devel

echo;echo now in p1
cd $test_dir
mkdir p1 && cd $_
git clone $test_dir/p0 .

mv $test_dir/p0 $test_dir/p0-bkup

git branch -a
git checkout main
git branch -a
ls -al

git remote set-url origin $test_dir/p0-bkup
git push
echo next git remote -v 
git remote -v
echo next ls -la $test_dir/p1/.git/refs/remotes/origin
ls -la $test_dir/p1/.git/refs/remotes/origin
echo I see HEAD only, AFAIK not as in fully set repo
git branch -vv

git checkout main
edit_file_and_commit "commit main-1 in p1"
git checkout -b qa

echo;echo now in p2
cd $test_dir
mkdir p2 && cd $_
git clone --mirror $test_dir/p1 ./.git
git config core.bare false
git status
git checkout main
git status
edit_file_and_commit "commit main-1 in p2"

print_and_run 'cat ./.git/config'
print_and_run 'git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main'
print_and_run 'cat ./.git/config'
print_and_run_2 sed --in-place -- "s|fetch = +refs/\*:refs/\*|fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*|" .git/config
set -x # Print shell input lines as they are read.
cat ./.git/config
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
cat ./.git/config

set +x 

exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now edit `.git/config` [to set the `fetch` line to read `+refs/*:refs/*`]

Don't do that.  That turns your regular repository into a mirror that discards your own work.<sup>1</sup>

> Why line for fetch affects `git branch --set-upstream-to`?

This is rather complicated, for historical reasons.  Let me end this section and, first, dive into technical details about *how* the upstream is represented.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, you keep your own *commits*.  What happens is that when you make commits that update your own *refs*, and then run `git fetch`, you lose the updated *refs* that let you *find* your own commits.  So while your new commits exist, you can no longer find them.  There are some workarounds, but this is generally just the wrong thing to do.

---

#### Representing the upstream of a branch

[As I've noted elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60035000/1256452), each (local) branch name can have one (1) *upstream* setting.  At the level one normally uses for interacting with Git, the upstream is a simple string, like `origin/xyzzy` for branch `xyzzy`, and we use `git branch --set-upstream-to` to set it, or `git branch --unset-upstream` to clear out the setting.

Internally, however, the upstream of branch `xyzzy` is represented in the `.git/config` file as *two* values:

```
branch.xyzzy.remote
branch.xyzzy.merge
```

When the upstream of branch `xyzzy` is `origin/xyzzy`, these two are *normally* set like this:

```
[branch "xyzzy"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/xyzzy
```

Note that this is *not* `merge = refs/remotes/origin/xyzzy`, but rather `merge = refs/heads/xyzzy`.  Why?  Well, this requires even more history; a brief sidebar here is appropriate as well.

#### Sidebar: [Refnames, branches, and tags, oh my!](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lions+and+tigers+and+bears+oh+my)

A Git repository is, internally, *primarily* just a big database of Git objects.  These objects store commits, which—at the Git object level—consist entirely of metadata that references one *tree* object and arbitrarily many other, previous commit objects.  The single distinguished tree object then, indirectly via more trees and/or blob objects, stores a full snapshot of your source files.  Since our lowest-level goal with Git is to store every version of every file ever committed, this accomplishes that goal.

Git finds its internal objects by hash IDs, e.g., `c48035d29b4e524aed3a32f0403676f0d9128863`.  These things are decidedly human-*hostile* (the opposite of human-friendly).  To let Git users refer t commits by *name*, as humans prefer to do, and also to solve several other problems all at once, Git allows us to use names.  Each Git repository therefore has a second, separate database, in which a name—a not quite arbitrary ASCII or Unicode text string—stores one hash ID.

The names are divided up into [*name spaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).  Most names, by far, start with the literal string `refs/`, which is then typically followed by a name-space-selector string such as `heads/` or `tags/` or `remotes/`.  These three distinguished names represent *branch names*, *tag names*, and *remote-tracking names* respectively.

Note that, regardless of the name-space in which the name resides, *all* of these entries are purely local to your own Git repository.  Any *other* Git repository has its own separate names database.  The names in your names database need not match the names in their names database.

Note: the objects in your Git *object* database exist as local copies as well, but the hash IDs in your database *match* the hash IDs in *every other Git database*, in that if you and they have an object with, e.g., hash ID `c48035d29b4e524aed3a32f0403676f0d9128863`, it's literally the *same* object.  That is, the Git hash ID is a universally (or globally) unique identifier or [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).  While this can't actually work forever (see [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433126/how-does-the-newly-found-sha-1-collision-affect-git)), it works well enough in practice, and it allows two different Git repositories to exchange only *new* objects during a `git fetch` or `git push` operation.  The key observation here—this is not relevant to your question but is something every Git user should know—is this: **objects are shared across different Git repositories, but names are not**.

#### Historic Git

Early Git did not have remote-tracking names; in fact, it did not even have *remotes* at all.  You never had an `origin`, you just had to type in the URL over and over again.  This was very obviously a problem and several different solutions were attempted.  Remnants of these attempts live on: see [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) and scroll down to the [**REMOTES**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_remotes) section, where the documentation mentions three ways to list a "remote".  The first method—a remote in the Git configuration file—is the only method one should use in modern Git.

Before remotes existed, though, one would run:

```
git fetch <url>
```

with an explicit URL every time, and your Git software would call up the other Git software as usual and they'd list out their refs.  Your Git would pore over *their* ref-names, as listed by their Git software, and select which one(s) seemed interesting, and observe the corresponding object UUIDs.  Then your Git would ask their Git to package up and send any missing objects, and would write, to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, the various branch and tag names that it found interesting, plus their hash IDs and such.

The `git fetch` command still does all of this to this day.  The `FETCH_HEAD` file format is unchanged from this early proto-Git.  The two other long-dead methods of defining a "remote" still work too.  **This all tells us something important about the Git authors' dedication to backwards compatibility: they keep it long past the point of usefulness, even if it seems weird.**  This is one of the keys to your answer.

Now, having run `git fetch`, we tend to like to *do* something with any new commits we've obtained.  This means running `git merge` or `git rebase`.  As a convenience, long ago, `git pull` was a simple shell script that:

- ran `git fetch` with URL and any additional branch name arguments, then
- fished out the interesting line(s) from `.git/FETCH_HEAD` and ran `git merge` with one or more raw hash IDs and an appropriate `-m` option to produce a merge message.

(The script was made fancier pretty quickly, to be able to run `git rebase` instead of `git merge` if you wanted, and now—more than a decade later—is a fancy C program that incorporates all of the fetch, merge, and rebase code in a single executable.  But it's still backwards compatible!)

Now, in those old days, to keep everything simple, the `git fetch` command would write `not-for-merge` to each `.git/FETCH_HEAD` line that was *not* supposed to have a hash ID passed to `git merge`, and would leave that line out for those lines that had a hash ID that *was* supposed to be passed to `git merge`.  This meant a simple `grep -v not-for-merge` picked out the right lines.  But to *put* those lines *into* `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, `git fetch` needed to know which branch name *was* "for merge".  So, once remotes were invented, `git fetch` would use these two settings:

```
branch.xyzzy.remote = origin
branch.xyzzy.merge = refs/heads/xyzzy
```

That told `git fetch` and/or `git pull`:

- which *remote* to use to get the URL;
- which *branch* (`refs/heads/xyzzy`) was the *interesting* one, "for merge", *on that remote*.

**This explains why the upstream setting in `.git/config` is convoluted.**  It's spelled out in two parts, with the `remote` value for `git fetch` or `git pull` to look up early, and with the `merge` setting for `git fetch` to look up later while writing `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  The `merge` setting in particular lists *the name of the branch as seen on the remote*.

#### Remote-tracking names and refspecs

With remotes came remote-tracking names.<sup>2</sup>  The idea behind the remote-tracking name is simple enough: now that we have a *name* for another Git repository, such as `origin`, why not have `git fetch` *record their branch names and hash IDs* locally?  Sure, the values are in `.git/FETCH_HEAD` after a `fetch`, but then they're *overwritten* as soon as we fetch from some *other* Git repository.<sup>3</sup>

Of course, our branch names are *our* branch names.  We can't have our Git overwrite out branch names!  They're *ours!*  So we have to have some other form of name, i.e., the remote-tracking form.  We'll take "their" branch name `xyzzy`, i.e., `refs/heads/xyzzy`, and turn it into *our* remote-tracking name `origin/xyzzy`, i.e., `refs/remotes/origin/xyzzy`.  By doing this for every branch name on the remote, we guarantee that *our* branch names and *their* branch names never collide.  That's the essential function of a namespace in the first place (see the Wikipedia article again if necessary).

But we need a mechanism for doing this name-rewrite.  One obvious choice for this mechanism would be just to hard-code it.  For whatever reason,<sup>4</sup> this isn't what Git ended up with.  Instead, the `remote` setting provides what Git calls a *refspec*, which is that `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` that you observed in your question.

This refspec *maps* names in one repository to names in another repository.  By listing more than one refspec, e.g.:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
fetch = +refs/notes/*:refs/remotenotes/origin/*
```

we can get Git to copy more names.  Whatever we want, refspecs can do it—well, up to some point, depending on how fancy the `*` match is.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>I was late enough coming to Git, around 1.5.7 perhaps, that I don't know if they came in two separate steps, though I think this was the case.  They were still pretty close in time, at least.

<sup>3</sup>You can use `git fetch --append`, aka `git fetch -a`, to *append* to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`; this clearly existed for use before remote-tracking names were invented.  As with the other backwards-compatibility features—including `.git/FETCH_HEAD` itself, at this point—it no longer serves any real purpose.

<sup>4</sup>I don't *know* the true reason, but I can speculate: at the time remotes and remote-tracking names were being discussed and developed, I have no doubt that Git mirrors were also being discussed and developed.  The mechanism chosen serves both purposes.

<sup>5</sup>Originally, `*` in refspec could only match whole "component names", spanning slashes but always coming "adjacent to" some slash, e.g., `refs/heads/*` is allowed and includes names like `refs/heads/feature/short`.  This was later extended to allow "partial component" matches, such as `refs/heads/pr-*`.  The rules for refspec matching are messy overall and Git gives you an error if a source name doesn't map to exactly one destination name.

---

#### Putting it all together

All of this history, plus the desire for backwards compatibility, produces the end result you've seen.  The *upstream setting* of a branch name, recorded in two parts in the `.git/config` file, refers to:

- the *named remote*, or `.` if the upstream is a local branch instead of a remote-tracking name; and
- the *branch name as seen on that remote* (or when the remote is `.`, it's the branch name as seen locally).

But Git *records* that branch name, as seen on that remote, under a *remote-tracking name*.  To compute the remote-tracking name—e.g., `origin/xyzzy`—from the `branch.xyzzy.merge` setting, Git must run the name through the refspec mapping function.  That refspec mapping function is determined by the `fetch` lines in the remote!

So, if and when you change the `fetch` lines, you must also *rename* any remote-tracking names.  This renaming *must* be nondestructive: e.g., it's OK to rename `origin` to `fred` if there's no existing remote named `fred` since there are no `refs/remotes/fred/*` names at this time, but it's *not* OK to rename `origin` to the empty string.

The `git remote` and `git branch` commands enforce enough rules to make this all work.  But if you short-cut them by editing `.git/config` yourself, you *must understand the underlying mechanisms*.  You won't precisely *break* anything (as in, Git won't *stop working*) but you may get bizarre and undesirable results, if you violate the normal mechanisms here.

Comment: Thanks, long answer will take some time to read. One question I have already: "Don't do that... turns into mirror". Well, I've mentioned mirror in the question already. Is editing fetch of the mirror to line from "ordinary" is all it takes to make mirror behave as ordinary (plus core.bare =false)? Cause I've recently asked about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778496/how-to-make-git-cloned-mirrored-repo-not-mirror?noredirect=1#comment131974915_74778496.

Comment: Finished reading, thanks a lot. I have one issue of practical importance on my mind. I've started to use `clone --mirror` to copy all objects. E.g. linux kernel AFAIK gives times more objects when copied with `--mirror`, w/out mirror one can only see work on current kernel, with `--mirror` repo gives also previous versions (accessed via tags). Recently with help of @joanis I saw even w/out `--mirror` cloned repo has files committed to non-current branch, so I'm not so sure about using `--mirror`. Do you know why/how many of kernel's objects are not cloned w/out  `--mirror`? TIA

Comment: There's a few more steps to convert from regular mirror to regular or vice versa: a *bare* repository (`core.bare` set to `true`) has no working tree, and therefore what would normally be in a hidden `.git` directory is sitting there, out in the open. A mirror repository made with `git clone --mirror` is a bare repository with the `+refs/*:refs/*` setting. So from "regular mirror" to "regular repo" means: change the fetch URL, clear the `core.bare` setting, and create `.git` and move everything there.

Comment: When cloning from hosting sites like GitHub or Bitbucket, using `--mirror` may (or may not) get you extra objects because some refs on those hosting sites are hosting-site-specific additions: GitHub use `refs/pull/`, Bitbucket use `refs/pull-requests/`, etc. If you pick up the ref, you must (except for the newfangled partial clone) get the target object as well. If you leave out the ref, you don't need the target object.

Comment: It's worth noting that when some sending Git *sends* objects or a (thin or otherwise) pack file *to* you, as GitHub and Bitbucket do when you clone or fetch, it's up to the sender to send everything they should send. If they send *more* than you ask for, what will your Git software do with the extra objects? Will it discard them, or will it keep them? That will depend on whose Git implementation you use and which version it is and how that one is programmed.

Comment: In practice, though, GItHub at least build a pack file that has only the desired objects (and I believe they cache this on their side with some custom software that's not in standard Git).

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I've noted in mirrored repo there is a line `mirror = true` in `origin` part after `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*`. What does it effect? You have not mentioned removing/editing it to convert to regular repo. TIA

Comment: It's not clear to me what `mirror = true` controls (perhaps nothing: it may be leftover ancient history). To find out, search the Git source code. I ran a quick `git grep core.mirror` and got zero hits, but that doesn't mean it's *not* used; `git grep mirror` gets *too many* hits that I'd have to spend some time narrowing things down.